# update an internal schema with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mean-stack

i'm having a problem with updating a member in schema that contained in other schema.

```
var User = new mongoose.Schema({
first_name               : { type: String, required: true , lowercase: true},
last_name                : { type: String, required: true , lowercase: true},
log                      : { type: [Log], default:  [Log] },
});


var Log = new mongoose.Schema({
left_groups                     : [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Group' }],
});
```

i'm trying to update the left_groups member (from the user) which is a reference to group schema and i can't do that.

after a research on the net, the best i came up with is:

```
User.update({_id: "549a972f243a461c093f8ebb"}, {log:{$push:{left_groups: gr}}}, function ()     {
        console.log("updated")
    });
```

and this seems not working for me.

//gr[0] means for group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i succeed to figure it out..

i'm not sure it's a proper solution though:

```
Group.findOne({_id: "549b18c73117388028c3990f"}, function (err, gr) {
    User.findOne({_id: '549b18c73117388028c39904'}, function(err, user){
        user.log[0].left_groups.push(gr);
        user.save();         
    });
})
```